# How to return correct local time in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select current_time at time zone 'GMT-2'
```

returns

```
"11:54:40.22045+02"
```

but correct local time in Windows is one hour different:

```
12:54
```

How to get correct local time ?

Using

"PostgreSQL 9.6.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 32-bit"

with  standard postgresql.conf file in Windows 10
Same issue occurs also in ealier Postgres and in earlier windows.

Server time in Windows is correct.

Daylight saving time was changed by one hour a week ago.
Maybe postgres didnt recognized it.

Comment: Might be this can help you:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Comment: and what time it shows without `at time zone`?

Comment: There was a DST change a few days ago. Most probably you are not in `'GMT-2'` anymore, Dorothy. (Sorry for the pun. Have you tried to use your named time-zone instead?)

Comment: @VaoTsun `select current_time` returns `"10:46:53.975868+00"` which is 3 hours different from windows time

Comment: @pozs `select current_time at time zone 'Europe/Tallinn'` returns correct time. Is it OK to use this in all postgres version starting from 8.1 ?

Comment: @Andrus yes. That's also the preferred. `'GMT-2'` is a time zone offset, not really a time zone. (and it's also be in the legacy, POSIX format, which is discuraged even in the offsets: use just `+2` f.ex. for an offset).

Comment: `localtime(0) at time zone 'Europe/Tallinn'` returns also correct time. Considering answer, is localtime better than current_time ?

Comment: @Andrus yes, @LaurenzAlbe is right: `time with time zone` usually doesn't make a lot of sense. It exists purely because of the SQL standard defines it (also, its only use case is when you want to add it to a (local) `date` to get `timestamp with time zone`. But still, it is rarely used.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `time with time zone`, it is a useless data type.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html):

> The type `time with time zone` is defined by the SQL standard, but the
>   definition exhibits properties which lead to questionable usefulness.
>   In most cases, a combination of `date`, `time`, `timestamp without time zone`,
>   and `timestamp with time zone` should provide a complete range of date/time
>   functionality required by any application.

Use `localtime` to get the current time at your current session time zone (defined by the `TimeZone` parameter).

Comment: `localtime at time zone 'GMT-2'` still returns `12:42...` but correct time is `13:42`  . How to get correct local time in windows default or hard coded Helsinki/Tallinn timezone without changing postgresql.conf ? `localtime` returns 10:45 which is even more wronger